# Zoom In on Canvas - C#

Tags: c#, image, canvas, zooming

I currently have a canvas that I load an image on in my program, and I would like to be able to right-click on a certain point on that image and click zoom in to zoom in on that point.

One solution I found was:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
         <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2">
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
```

This works however it doesn't zoom in to the specific coordinates but rather just zooms in to the top-left of the image. How would I implement coordinate zooming? zooming in on specific coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using three separate transforms. One to move the canvas so that the click point is the origin. The second transform to scale and the third to put the click point back at the center again

```
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
  <TransformGroup>
    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
  </TransformGroup>
</Canvas.RenderTransform>


private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = e.GetPosition(this);

    var transformGroup = ImageCanvas.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
    var moveToOriginTransform = transformGroup.Children[0] as TranslateTransform;
    var scaleTransform = transformGroup.Children[1] as ScaleTransform;
    var moveBackTransform = transformGroup.Children[2] as TranslateTransform;

    moveToOriginTransform.X = -p.X;
    moveToOriginTransform.Y = -p.Y;

    scaleTransform.ScaleX += 1;
    scaleTransform.ScaleY += 1;

    moveBackTransform.X = p.X;
    moveBackTransform.Y = p.Y;
}
```